# How can I explain to non programmers that nothing is random except for Radioactive Decay?

Tags: random

I am talking to my father and his friend(Richard). Richard thinks his other friend, who is a Math Professor would say otherwise. Then explains how when he goes to a casino pulling the lever will give you a random result. I then explain someone had to program the slot machine to have the result show up out of a list of other combinations. The way the programmer decided to pull the number up can not be random.

He then says "The programmer coded it so it can choose a number from out of a billion", which brings me back to my original statement. It was really hard to convince him, me being a programmer, and him being a gambler. At the end I gave up.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator for an explanation of hardware random number generators. There is more to random than radioactive decay. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation for general background on RNG.

Comment: I love this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to explain that nothing is random except for radioactive decay to ***anybody*** because you're wrong.  The concept of "random" is actually a model for lack of *a priori* predictability, and lack of predictability can happen for many reasons.

One fairly broad concept that leads to unpredictability is [observability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability), introduced by Rudolf Kalman (who invented Kalman filtering) in his analyses of linear dynamic systems. In rough terms, suppose we have a system that transforms inputs to outputs by incorporating both the inputs and an internal state space. If an observer of the inputs and outputs cannot infer that internal state in finite time, the system is said to be unobservable. Without knowledge of the internal state you can't predict with certainty what the next output of the system will be, even if you know what the inputs are. Even though the behavior of the system is completely deterministic, the outputs are unpredictable in the absence of knowledge of the internal state! At that point the best you can do is apply probability models to describe the relative likelihood of landing in the various particular output states. For all we know, this may be what's really happening with radioactive decay. If the string theorists are correct and the universe is actually a 4-dimensional projection of an 11-dimensional (or whatever the current vogue is) space, the lack of predictability of radioactive decay may just be an artifact of the lack of observability of the higher dimensions. Consequently, we model what we see using a Poisson distribution to describe the number of observed decay events per time unit or an exponential distribution for the time between decay events and say the phenomenon is random.

It's certainly true that most PRNGs are provably non-random, but that's because they weren't constructed to be non-observable.  With enough observations you can infer the internalized state and make perfect predictions of what will happen next.  Cryptographically strong PRNG's, on the other hand, are specifically designed to be non-observable.  Similarly, when you incorporate state from `/dev/random`, you're effectively introducing a non-observable state into the generating sequence, thus making it unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Explain that for a computer to do anything involves a step by step formula (key word being "formula") resulting in everything being "formulaic"?
2. Perhaps then show that [Turing Completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) or at least [functional completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) can be achieved using only a few simple operators (eg. AND, OR and NOT). None of which involves any uncertainty.